# Using Gehan’s test and Tarone and Ware weights

Tags: r

I'm trying to use Gehan’s test and Tarone and Ware weights for testing the hypothesis of no difference in the rate of staphylococcus infection between patients whose burns were cared for with a routine bathing care method versus those whose body cleansing was initially performed using 4% chlorhexidine gluconateon the data (burn) from (KMsurv).
1.When using the code `(gehan.test(T3, D3, Z1)`, I got an error message says gehan.test not found.
2. Regarding to Tarone and Ware, what is the appropriate code that could be used?

Comment: Try the __npsm__ package. The `gehan.test` function is not in any of the standard R "base" packages, including stats.

Comment: And please remember to appropriately acknowledge the answers provided by the kind people here. People start to remember those who fail to repeatedly do so. ;)

Comment: I was looking for that icon to accept the answer, I could not find it. I figured it out finally.Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **npsm** package has the `gehan.test` function.

```
library(npsm)
library(KMsurv)  # Contains the "burn" data

data(burn)  # see ?burn for a description of the variables.

# T3: Time to straphylocous aureaus infection or on study time
# D3: Straphylocous aureaus infection: 1=yes 0=no
# Z1: Treatment: 0-routine bathing 1-Body cleansing

with(burn, gehan.test(time=T3, event=D3, trt=Z1) )
```

---

```
statistic =  -1.686689 , p-value =  0.0916631
```

The difference in the rate of staphylococcus infection between patients whose burns were cared for with routine bathing and body cleansing is not significant (p>0.05).

Now for the Tarone-Ware test. This is available in the **coin** package.

```
library(coin)
?logrank_test
```

The usage is described in the help page. We need a formula of the form `y ~ x | block` where `y` is a a survival object and `x` is factor. Z1 is not a factor and neither are any of the other "Z" variables in the burn dataset. So convert them all to factors. I'll use the `mutate_at` function from the **dplyr** package for this.

```
library (dplyr)

  burn <- burn %>%
             mutate_at(vars(starts_with("Z")), as.factor)

unlist(lapply(burn, class)) # Just to check
```

You could also add the labels. And now the test:

```
logrank_test(Surv(T3, D3) ~ Z1, data=burn, type="Tarone-Ware")
```

---

```
    Asymptotic Two-Sample Tarone-Ware Test

data:  Surv(T3, D3) by Z1 (0, 1)
Z = -1.7694, p-value = 0.07683
alternative hypothesis: true theta is not equal to 1
```

There is no evidence to suggest that the survival distributions are different between the two groups.

Comment: When running the code: logrank_test(Surv(T3, D3) ~ Z1, data=burn, type="Tarone-Ware") , this error message appears: could not find function "logrank_test".                How can I define  logrank_test?

Comment: Did you install and load the `coin` package?

Comment: Yes. Now I got this message for obtaining both tests ( Tarone-Ware and Gehan):                 Error in check(object) :  ‘object’ does not represent a K-sample problem (maybe the grouping variable is not a factor?)                                                                                                                   the code used:                                                                                               gehantest<-logrank_test(Surv( T3 , D3) ~ Z1, type = c("Gehan-Breslow"), data = burn)
gehantest

logrank_test(Surv(T3, D3) ~ Z1, data=burn, type="Tarone-Ware")

Comment: You have to convert the "Z1" variable to a factor. Please check my answer again: `burn <- burn %>%
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("Z")), as.factor)`

Comment: I have attempted that. It did not work too.                                                                                  Error in mutate_at(vars(starts_with("Z")), as.factor) : 
  could not find function "mutate_at"

Comment: You have to load the `dplyr` package. :)  Sorry, I forgot to mention that in my answer.

Comment: After installing it, I run the code again but I got the same message error :(

Comment: It worked after I used this code 'burn$Z1<-as.factor(burn$Z1)' instead of the code you have shared. Thank you!

Comment: Type `library (dplyr)`. Then run my code to mutate at every "Z" variable. Your method is perfectly OK, but you may have many variables to convert. My one-liner does them all. ☺

Answer (score 0):

It seems that gehan.test is not working anymore.

But there's a repo in gitbhub that provides the function:

```
gehan.test<-function(time,event,trt) {


  #  number of times x clearly beats y - number of times y clearly beats x

  if( length(unique(trt)) != 2 ) stop("trt must have two levels")

  nvec<-table(trt)

  n<-sum(nvec)
  U<-matrix(0,nrow=n,ncol=n)
  D<-sign(outer(time,time,'-'))     

  ind11<-outer(event,event,'&')
  ind01<-outer(!event,event,'&')
  ind10<-outer(event,!event,'&')

  U[ind11]<-D[ind11]
  U[ind01&(D>=0)]<- 1
  U[ind10&(D<=0)]<- -1

  W<-apply(U,1,sum)

  statistic<-sum(W[trt==trt[1]])/sqrt(prod(nvec)/sum(nvec)*var(W))

  res<-list(statistic=statistic,p.value=2*pnorm(abs(statistic),lower.tail=FALSE))

  class(res)<-'rank.test'

  res

}
```

credits to: https://github.com/cran/npsm

Comment: Really? I just installed and downloaded the npsm package from CRAN and it seems to work.

Comment: is not working in the base R. never said the package was not working